# Why are there two different scale estimates in GAM model with mgcv

Tags: mixed-model, generalized-additive-model, mgcv

Im am doing some modelling with the mgcv package, specifically the gam function

```
glm.mod1 <- gam(imp1 ~ s(pH1, bs = 're') + s(ZnAc, bs = 're') + s(filter.age1, bs = 're'), 
                family = quasi(link = 'inverse', variance = 'mu^2'), method = 'REML')
```

When I want to extract the variance components, the last component is called scale

```
gam.vcomp(glm.mod1)

Standard deviations and 0.95 confidence intervals:

                    std.dev        lower       upper
s(pH1)         0.0164750427 0.0035519282 0.076416813
s(ZnAc)        0.0281406417 0.0062903029 0.125891507
s(filter.age1) 0.0009649886 0.0002380628 0.003911585
scale          0.7354211808 0.7061853013 0.765867418

Rank: 4/4
```

What confuses me is why this scale parameter is different from the scale returned by

```
glm.mod1$scale
[1] 0.4863872
```

As far as I can tell the value returned by `glm.mod1$scale` is the dispersion parameter of the underlying distribution, but what is the scale in `gam.vcomb()` then?